# USB/Wireless Headset Issues

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, microphone

I am having troubles getting my Sennheiser GSP 670 to work on Ubuntu 21.04.  On fresh install it worked however I didn't have the microphone input available.  In try to resolve that I seem to have broken it entirely.

I installed the custom profiles provided at https://github.com/szszoke/sennheiser-gsp670-pulseaudio-profile/tree/new-dongle-firmware

I am on the new firmware so have installed the new firmware branch of the repo.

http://alsa-project.org/db/?f=12c1a1c239857f12e3edc56779cbc705f831c0ed

When I go to the sound menu in settings the I only have a digital spdif that I assume to be the mobo sound card and 2 HDMI outputs.  I have no inputs that I can select.

I am not sure what else to try and would be open to suggestions or direction on how to resolve.

Thanks in advance.

J
I can see the device show up when I aplay -l and am linking the aplay-info here

Comment: So I found another post that suggested manually loading the module for the headset by doing pactl load-module module-alsa-sink device=hw:X,X where X=device hardware id.  That did work at least for the time being as far as sound.  I am not sure why this is not getting loaded automatically since it appears the profiles would do this.

Comment: Can You confirm that both sound and microphone work on ubuntu? I am planning on buying this headset.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seemed to come with the new firmware. With the new firmware, the recording device is not working anymore. It seems that this has been fixed with a new kernel version, but sadly there's not yet an Ubuntu kernel with this patch.

There is more information about this issue on [github](https://github.com/szszoke/sennheiser-gsp670-pulseaudio-profile/issues/13).